# Removing trailing slash between directory and url query in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm making a blog in PHP. I want people to be able to load a page using a url query, for example:

> blog.mysite.com/article?a=my_cool_article

I don't actually have an "article" directory, I just have a file named `article.php`

I am using the following in .htaccess to internally redirect requests:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^article?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/?$ /article\.php?article=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It works fine, but when I try to use it, it adds a slash between `article` and `?`.. It changes the url to look like this:

> blog.mysite.com/article/?a=my_cool_article

I've tried a heap of solutions on here and can't find anything that works. Thanks for taking the time to read!

---

Here are my existing rules:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^article?([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/?$ /article\.php?article=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteOptions inherit
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "https://www.example.com"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "https://example.com"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "https://*.example.com"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "https://src.example.com"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "https://example.com/*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<Files error_log>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>
```

Comment: Do you have any other rewrite rules in your current or parent htaccess files? It does not add a trailing slash on a vanilla 2.4 apache installation.

Comment: Still does not add a trailing slash. How about commenting `RewriteOptions inherit` out to see if it's because of parent directory rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a trailing slash you can use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```